# Function name for returning a struct

Tags: c, struct

I want to make a function in which I change an already existing struct. So the return value of that function should be a struct. If I want an `int` as return value I call the function "`int example()`" ... How do I call the function if I want to return a struct? Since "struct" is already taken — I already take "`struct whatever`" to create one.

Comment: If the struct type you want to return is `struct whatever`, write `struct whatever example(void);` as the function prototype (or `struct whatever example(struct whatever arg);` or `struct whatever example(struct whatever *argp)`).  Use the already existing structure name -- you need to use that to be able to assign the result over the existing structure variable.

Comment: Basically if you have `struct foo { int x; int y; int z; int b}` you can alter it: `foo.x = 10;` pass to  a function `testFoo(foo);` and return as `return foo`

Comment: So to sum it up - I got a struct called "struct coordinates" . Then, if I want to change its values (say multiply each coordinate with something) I can make a function called "struct coordinates ScalarMultiplication()"and in that function write like "coordinates.x  *=  a"?

Comment: See @nneonneo's answer. If you pass a pointer to the function, you can modify items in the struct with code like `coordinates->x *= a;` If you pass the structure and return a modified structure, you're wasting a lot of time copying the unmodified items of the struct.

Comment: Sorta.  If you want to pass in the value and modify it, you need to pass it as a pointer, and you don't need the function to return a new value: `void ScalarMultiplication(struct coordinates *c, int a) { c->x *= a; c->y *= a; }` would do the job (and call: `struct coordinates c0 = { 2, 3 }; ScalarMultiplication(&c0, 4);).  Or you could use `struct coordinates ScalarMultiplication(struct coordinates c, int a) { c.x *= a; c.y *= a; return c; }` and call it as `c0 = ScalarMultiplication(c0, 4);` with the same result.

Comment: return a structure by a function is not a good idea as the return will be stored in the stack and which could lead if it is a big data to stackoverflow @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @Meninx: it is perfectly legal, and even sensible for small structures; it is not sensible for big structures.  The boundary between small and big is ill-defined, and depends in part on your tolerance level.

Comment: what I meant is that it should not be taken as a general rule but in some cases  with cautious especially for embedded systems

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guy, appreciate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the function to modify an existing struct, you should pass the struct in by pointer:

```
void modify_thing(struct whatever *thing);
```

If you want to return a modified *copy* of the struct, you can return the struct by value:

```
struct whatever edit_thing(const struct whatever *input);
```

Note that it is usually more efficient to pass struct variables by pointer, rather than by value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this case I have the (learning)task to return the modified struct in the edit_thing function. So for an appropriate example: "struct coordinates ScalarMultiplication(float* multiplier) would be correct?

Comment: @Yíu: You said you were modifying an existing struct, so `struct coordinates ScalarMultiplication(const struct coordinates *coords, float *multiplier)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ah sure, I also need to retrieve the existing coords. Could you further explain what that "const" means? Wouldnt "struct coordinates *coords" be enough?

Comment: If you're returning a modified copy, you don't want to accidentally modify the struct you pass in. `const` tells the compiler that the input should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

passing a struct by value will cause the compiler to establish 1 or more reserved areas in memory that can only be used for that function.

Each of those memory areas are manipulated by the compiler inserting calls to memcpy().

Much better to pass a pointer to the struct, then return a simple indication of success/failure of the struct update operation.